# Laravel 9 - Destroy Session when close tab no close the browser

Tags: laravel

hi I need to understand how to destroy the active session when I close the tab without log out, with the browser part I have already done it like this:

expire_on_close : true

so now i would like to figure out how to destroy the session by closing the tab thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted any code which you've done so far, assuming you're done with login and logout routes in your laravel application. You can do something like this with a combination of server side and client side techniques.

Client-side technique:

Add an event listener to the beforeunload or unload event of the window object.
In the event listener, make an AJAX request to a server-side route that will destroy the user's session. The code can be included in the master file for your views, and on each close the session will be destroyed on closing the tab or closing the browser.

Example code for client-side technique:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/logout', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
    xhr.send();
});
```

Server-side technique:

Create a new Laravel route that will destroy the user's session.
Add a middleware to the route that will verify the CSRF token to prevent CSRF attacks.

Example code for server-side technique:

```
Route::post('/logout', function () {
    session()->flush();
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Session destroyed.']);
})->middleware('verified');
```

Comment: very kind I use breeze in fact everything is already written for this I have not published the code, I tried your methods it is not what I am looking for, my problem is to destroy the active session by closing the browser tab because with the total closure I have already succeeded ... I would need a bit of home banking when you close the tab and reopen a new one you can log in with another account.. consequently the previous session is destroyed without closing the browser but only the tab

A thousand thanks

Comment: then simply use the client side example code which can logout and change the `beforeunload` to `unload` or `window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {`  it'll work for you

Comment: Both unload and beforeunload are JavaScript events that are fired when the user leaves a page. However, there are some differences between the two events.

The unload event is fired when the page is being unloaded, which can happen when the user closes the browser, navigates to another page, or reloads the current page. The unload event does not give you the ability to cancel the page unload, and any synchronous requests made during this event may not complete successfully.

Comment: On the other hand, the beforeunload event is fired just before the page is being unloaded, giving you the ability to cancel the unload process by returning a string value from the event handler. This string will be displayed in a confirmation dialog box asking the user if they want to leave the page. This can be useful if you want to prevent the user from accidentally leaving the page, such as if they have unsaved changes.

Comment: I tried the client side method and unfortunately it doesn't reflect what I would like. I would just like that when the tab is closed, you log out or destroy the session

Comment: Well. I'm shooting in the dark and without any way to replicate this issue on my end i cannot answer any further, this methods works for me well. You may have an issue like cache or something. You can check it on your own.

Comment: A thousand thanks